# Angular script working on app html but not in other modules

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, module, lazy-loading

I am using angular, and I have this two script here inside index.html, theses scripts are used in the navbar component ( this navebar is inside "shared module" ,
in app.module :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
//modules
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
declarations: \[
AppComponent
\],
imports: \[
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
SharedModule,

\],
providers: \[\],
bootstrap: \[AppComponent\]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

in app.routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FeaturesComponent } from './features/features.component';

const routes: Routes = \[
{
path: 'feature',
component: FeaturesComponent,
loadChildren: () =\> import('./features/features.module').then(m =\> m.FeaturesModule) },
\];

@NgModule({
imports: \[RouterModule.forRoot(routes)\],
exports: \[RouterModule\]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

in features module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { FeaturesRoutingModule } from './features-routing.module';
import { FeaturesComponent } from './features.component';
mport { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

//component
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: \[
FeaturesComponent,
DashboardComponent
\],
imports: \[
CommonModule,
FeaturesRoutingModule,
SharedModule

\]
})
export class FeaturesModule { }
```

so when i use <app-navbar></app-navbar> in app.component.html everything works fine
bu when i use <app-navbar></app-navbar> in features.component.html the script used in the navbar is not working like i can see the navbar and all but the script declared in the index is not working

I want the <app-navbar> in my features module

Comment: What are the errors in the console?

Comment: there's no errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.